# Python index, item printing correctly, but doing it the same number of characters in item

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

The following is code I've written to work out a shopping list. What I'd like to do is have users enter the item to purchase, the quantity and price before tax. At the end of each entry, I'd like to see a rolling list and the option to add another item. If the user doesn't want to add an item, then menu options will appear asking if they want to Add, Delete, See List or Quit.

The codes I'm having trouble with are headlined with comments. Other comments are just explaining my thought process when assigning variables and such.

I'm new at this so if it looks odd that would be why. This program is stemmed from an assignment, but I'm trying to add more to it. Our instructor wants us to use classes, but I am more comfortable with the program as follows right now so thought maybe if I did that first and moved pieces into the classes it would work. Any advice or resolution to the comments below would be great.

```
    menu_options = {'A': "Add Item", 'D': "Delete Item", 'E': "Edit Item", 'S': "See List", 'Q': "Quit"} ## for later use
    shopping_list = {'Items': 0, 'Quantity': 0, 'Total Cost': 0} ##To create storage for later use -- at the end of the program I'd like a final list with Quantity and total estimated cost.
    item_list = [] ## to create an empty list
    repeat = True

    while repeat == True:
        repeat = False

        while True:
            item = input('Enter the item you wish to purchase: ')
            print(item)

            quantity = int(input('How many would you like to buy? '))
            print(quantity)

            price = float(input('What is the price before tax? '))
            print('$', price)

    ##This items part below is taking the user input from item above and is printing fine, except it is printing the same item and print output the same number of characters. So if the user entered hat, 1, 5, it would print 1. hat, 1 of them, $5.0 each. But it will print three of the hat lines. So 2. hat, 1.... and 3. would be hat.... Can't figure out how to stop this.
            items = item
            number = 1                                   
            for str in item:   # print numbered entries
                print ('Shopping List\n', number,'.', item, ',', quantity, 'of them,', '$',price, 'each.')
                number = number + 1   # crucial added line

            add_another = input('Add another item? [y/n] > ')
            repeat = True if add_another == 'y' else False
            if add_another == 'n':
                break
    ##I would like this part to loop each time a user performs an action A, D or S.
        while add_another == 'n':
            user_opt = input("Would you like to [A]dd, [D]elete, [S]ee List or [Q]uit? > ")
            user_opt = user_opt.upper()
            if user_opt in menu_options:
                break
            else:
                print("You must enter an A, D, S or Q") ## At the time a user enters Q, I would like the shopping list storage part (above) to run.

    ##From this point down nothing works. The line "you must enter..." lets input be received, but it doesn't prompt anything below.

            if user_opt == 'A':
                add_more = input('Add another item? [y/n] > ')
                repeat = True if add_more == 'y' else False
                item.append(item)
                print("Item added.")

              if user_opt == 'D':
                  remove_item = input("What number of the item would you like to remove? > ')
                  item_list.remove(item)
                  print("Item removed.")

    # I stopped writing code until I can get these things resolved.

UPDATE:
Output:
Enter the item you wish to purchase: oranges
oranges
How many would you like to buy? 6
6
What is the price before tax? .35
$ 0.35
Shopping List
 1 . oranges , 6 of them, $ 0.35 each.
Shopping List
 2 . oranges , 6 of them, $ 0.35 each.
Shopping List
 3 . oranges , 6 of them, $ 0.35 each.
Shopping List
 4 . oranges , 6 of them, $ 0.35 each.
Shopping List
 5 . oranges , 6 of them, $ 0.35 each.
Shopping List
 6 . oranges , 6 of them, $ 0.35 each.
Shopping List
 7 . oranges , 6 of them, $ 0.35 each.
Add another item? [y/n] > n
Would you like to [A]dd, [D]elete, [S]ee List or [Q]uit? > A
>>>
```

Comment: Does it even compile? This line is wrong `remove_item = input("What number of the item would you like to remove? > ')`. Missing `"`.

Comment: It compiles partly. I'll update my code to show the output. - Thanks for the missing end quote mark.

Comment: `for str in item:` this executes for each character in item string. also dont use str as a variable name. Not sure what you want to achieve with this for loop.

Comment: What I'm wanting to do is just print a numbered list of each item. So after a user puts data in, then the numbered item will print. So in my output, I just want oranges to be #1, then say the user enters apples, that would be #2, and so on until the user deletes something or quits.

Comment: There are a bit mistakes in your code. For example, you dont add any times to `item_list`. I think item should be added to item_list, and you want for loop to loop over items in the item_list. Also dont know what is this: ` items = item`. You are even not using items variable anywhere. Should it be items_list?

Comment: Yes, it should be item_list, but when I do that the character prints down the list instead of the whole word, that's why I changed it to a string. Eg. I changed it to item_list and entered apple. 1. a 2. p 3. p. etc...